# outdated files when downloading in vaadin (java)

Tags: java, file, download, vaadin7, txt

At creating the button, set the ID:

```
    btnTran.setId("DownloadButtonID");
```

so code can start the download, when files are created:

```
    Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute(
        "document.getElementById('DownloadButtonID').click();");
```

If I use `btnTran.click()`, for some reason does not work, so I use java script above. But that is not big of a deal.

Anyway, when files are created, code runs the download with `FileDownloader`:

```
    FileDownloader fileDownloader1, fileDownloader2, fileDownloader3;

    fileDownloader1 = new FileDownloader(new FileResource(file1));
    fileDownloader2 = new FileDownloader(new FileResource(file2));
    fileDownloader3 = new FileDownloader(new FileResource(file3));
    
    fileDownloader1.extend(btnTran);
    fileDownloader2.extend(btnTran);
    fileDownloader3.extend(btnTran);
```

Problem: many times downloaded files would be from cache (probably) and outdated. I have to use `Ctrl + F5` to get current version of files. But clearing cache is not an option for me. What am I doing wrong ? Thanks!

Comment: You need to generate unique filename for each download, e.g. by adding a timestamp to the name, or random number for cache busting.

Comment: Yes, but what if I want the same file name every time ?

Comment: If you want to have the same file name, then you need to accept caching. You select either or. This is how Browser works.